# Interface Builder Constraints --> UITextView flattening out when run

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, uitextview

So I am using interface builder (which I don't often use), and I have two storyboards, one for iPhone 5+ and one for iPhone 4. The iPhone 5 one works perfectly.

However, when I run the app in an iPhone 4 or 4s, one of the UITextViews shrinks in size like it has deflated. When I use constraints, I usually put the views where I want them then do `Editor -> Resolve AutoLayout Views` or something, and normally the views snap into place.

Here is what it looks like in IB:
[IB constraints](http://i.gyazo.com/ce66aaade92a4f5147962b0fe79c8b41.png)

And this is what I get when I run the app:
[The UITextView when I run the app](http://i.gyazo.com/01e57f298c70c38e44cf308def2cdee1.png)

This is probably a really simple mistake, but I do feel like a bit of a doompf with my pancake like UITextView. Does anyone know what constraints I could add/actions I could take in order to make the UITextView the size it is in the storyboard?

I am in Xcode 6 and I am using auto layout.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit** Solved:

Firstly, I deleted the 3.5 inch storyboard so I only have one storyboard.
Then I selected the view in question, and fiddled around with the different iPhone sizes. Once I had put constraints that look good on all the devices, I ran it on every phone, and it worked :).

Comment: You shouldn't have to be using two different storyboards. Well you can, but it will make programming increasingly difficult. Just read any tutorial on constrainst in xcode and your problem should be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Minestroni-Soup that you don't necessarily need to use two distinct storyboards. In any case, here's how I'd approach the problem. First, I'll ignore the horizontal direction because your problem happens in the vertical direction. If you have problems with the horizontal direction, post a new question.

Place constraints of fixed heights between vertically adjacent views in your layout, and also between the top view and the top border, and also between the bottom view and the bottom border. Then create a constraint that sets the height of one UITextView to be the same as the height of the other UITextView. That should solve your problem.

```
top border
constraint to set a vertical space of some amount
label 1
constraint to set a vertical space of some amount
textview 1
constraint to set a vertical space of some amount
label 2
constraint to set a vertical space of some amount
textview 1
constraint to set a vertical space of some amount
bottom border
```

Note that the above, alone, doesn't uniquely define the heights of the two text views but if you add a constraint that sets their heights to be the same, then all the constraints together will have a unique solution (because the labels have well-defined default heights).

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: I have reduced the total amount of storyboards to 1. When I run it on the iPhone 5 both textviews show the correct size, but on the 4 the issue persists. I have added your suggested constraints, but they don't seem to work. Thank you for helping :)